# iPhone - custom chevron icon

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to swap out the icon for `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton` with a custom icon?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Set the `accessoryView` to a custom image view.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in viewForAnnotation:

```
UIButton *advertButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
advertButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 23);
advertButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
advertButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;

[advertButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button-image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[advertButton addTarget:self action:@selector(advertFunction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = advertButton;
```

Dont forget to include the image in your app and the function the selector is assigned too.